# Adding css classes to html element dynamically in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to build an application which has many courses.Each course has some days(e.g. 14 days or for another course 20 days).And to keep track on this I have a step progress bar.Which look like this:[image]

Now in this example 14 days which are big circles with a lock icon.small circles in between are test quiz.

I am using laravel for this. I am fetching all this data from the database and producing this step progress bar like this:

```
     <ul class="progressbar">
        @for($i=1;$i< $totalDays->total_days*2;$i++)
          <li class=""></li>
        @endfor    
     </ul>
```

Now I want to add the active class to the active day (on which day currently is).

Like This:

```
<li class="active"></li>
```

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: first get the current learning day of the user. then put the condition in the class attribaute  <li class="<?php echo ($i < $curr_day) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"></li>

Comment: @NitinGoyal Thank you for the reply. Adding this code it will add the active class to quiz circles(small circles)also. I want to add it only to big circles with a lock icon.

Comment: add more condition to it.. like $i%2 != 0

Comment: <li class="{{$i==$current_day && $i%2 != 0 ?'active':''}}"></li> like this

Comment: Doing that when  $current_day is even number it doesn't add class anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do this:

```
<li class="<?php if ($i/2 == $current_day-0.5) { echo "active"; } ?>"></li>
```

It checks if the day number (`$current_day`) equals to the number of the circle (`$i`), if yes, it adds the class `active` to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Adding this code it will add the active class to quiz circles(small circles)also. I want to add it only to big circles with a lock icon.

Comment: does the code add the class to the correct big circle or it added it to the wrong one.

Comment: if $current_day is 1 then it adds to the first li circle. if $current_day = 2 then it will add active class to the second small circle which i don't want

Comment: @RakeshKohali Yeah, i get you, the edit by Nitin Goyal should have solved it. Credit to him :)

Comment: Doing that when  $current_day is even number it doesn't add class anywhere.

Comment: This  also is not working and I think $i <= $current_day would be $i == $current_day  ??

Comment: @RakeshKohali could u please post a screenshot of the result of the code? it really should be working, thx

Comment: When `$current_day = 1` result:  https://prnt.sc/ipa9g6   when `$current_day = 2` result: https://prnt.sc/ipaa4d   when `$current_day =3` result: https://prnt.sc/ipaali   `$current_day=4` result:https://prnt.sc/ipab2l   `$current_day = 5`  result: https://prnt.sc/ipabn0

Comment: @RakeshKohali please try this: <li class="<?php if ($i*2-1 == $current_day) { echo "active"; } ?>"></li>

Comment: @RakeshKohali ok please replace the if statement with this: `$i/2 == $current_day-0.5 ` 100% sure it wold work, i'm sorry for all those wrong codes